# CSS adaptive grid style placement of blocks

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a container for an unspecified amount of blocks that all have the same size.

- I'd like the container to place as many blocks in a row as will fit,
  then wrap to the next row.
- When there is space available, I'd like the blocks to grow in size.
- I'd like all blocks to have the same size. It's fine if this causes a gap on the bottom row.

[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

The first two constraints are achievable with flexbox, but the issue I run into is that if there are not enough blocks to fill the last row, those blocks become elongated compared to the others. I'd like all blocks to have the same size. So far I haven't figured out a way to do this with flexbox.

I've been trying my hand at CSS grid, and it does allow me to keep all blocks at the same size. However, I'm running into another snag. I don't know how many columns will be required, so I'm using `repeat(auto-fit,<track size>)`. To use auto-fit, the track size must be *definite*.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto); /* does what I want, but the amount of columns is fixed */
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(350px,1fr)); /* does what I want, but I'd like the min-size to be defined on the cell */
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(min-content,1fr)); /* invalid */
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/Thoronwen/pen/bGVGoNg

It feels wrong to me that the minimum block size must be defined on the grid.
I intend to use this grid style placement in more than one place in my project, and for each place the content of the blocks will be different. Some may need more width than others.
Why would I need a different grid definition if it's just the cells that are different? I'd like to define the min-width on the block, not in the grid, like I can with flexbox.

It feels like this should be possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: `When there is space available, I'd like the blocks to grow in size.` And `I'd like all blocks to have the same size.` Contradict each other because if you want element to grow if there's space you can just `flex:1 0 50px;`

Comment: I don't what the blocks in the bottom row to grow wider than those in the other rows. They *can* leave a gap.

Comment: What I think you are after is `autofil1` rather than `autofit`.

You do have to specify a minimum track size but otherwise I thin it check most of your boxes.

Comment: What would the correct syntax be for that? For example ```repeat(auto-fill,minmax(100px,auto))``` makes all cells 100px instead of the blocks' min-width

Comment: not `auto`, use `1fr`

Comment: It may not be a complete solution but I think it gets you a long way down the road.

Comment: That also makes all cells 100px. (Using Chrome 80 to test)